# Where to find Okocim beer in or around Pennsylvania

Tags: distribution, pennsylvania

I'm looking for distributors/shops close to central Pennsylvania that sell Okocim beers such as Okocim Porter, Okocim Beer, or Okocim Mocne.  I've seen O.K. Beer around here (another Okocim product), but the branded Okocim beers are what I'm really interested in.  I don't mind driving a bit either, but hopefully something in or around the state...

Comment: I called several distributors in New Jersey and New York yesterday who purportedly carried Okocim, but all they had were the O.K. There is a wholesale distributor of Polish beers in Brooklyn, New York, called [Amtec International](http://yespils.com/index.php?&path=home), who may be willing to refer you to some retailers in Pennsylvania. Good luck in your search.

Comment: I've checked around, and O.K. Beer seems to be what most people carry...  That's quite a shame too, because it just doesn't do justice to the brand.  Thanks for checking into it though!

Comment: Have you checked beermenus.com? That's where I usually go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okocim Beer is part of the Carlsberg group. According to [Carlsbergs site](http://www.carlsberggroup.com/Markets/ExLid/Pages/USA.aspx) it looks like they are distributed in the USA by St. Killian.

St. Killian has a [beer finder page](http://stkillian.com/beers/beer-finder/) that lets you search for bars, resturants, or stores that sell particular products by zip code. When typing in the zip code for State College, Pennsylvania, I'm not sure where you are located but this is pretty central, it shows four locations within 100 miles.

You could put in your zip code and then select see what is near. I'd call before making the trip and see which Okocim beers they actually sell since the comments seem to suggest that some only carry O.K..